# Zebra Stripe PHP MYSQL Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I would like to Zebra Stripe the results table.  I can't find a solid solution.  What would I need to do to this table to add a odd/even class to the results rows?

```
 // HTML ... Aliases from Mysql
echo "<table  class='sortable' id='tablesorter' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='920px' >
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='header'>Short Name of Fund</th>
<th class='header'>I/C</th>
<th class='header'>Fund Manager Company</th>
<th class='header'>Class</th>
<th class='header'>Special Class</th>
<th class='header' id='custom'>TTR year-to-date<br /> %</th>
<th class='header'>Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged</th>
<th class='header id='custom'>Total Expenses <br /> %</th>
<th class='header'>Fund Size</th>
</thead><tbody>

</tr>";

//<tr> specifies table row. for each <td> (table data) will specify a new column.  The $row specifies the mysql column name (in this case using an alias)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"page.php?id={$row['ID']}\">{$row['Short Name of Fund']}</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['I/C'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fund Manager Company'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Special Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TTR year-to-date %'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Total Expenses %'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fund Size'] . "</td>";


  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, the syntax may be incorrect as I have not tested it. But the logic is there.

```
$currentState = 'odd';
$html = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $currentState = ($currentState == 'odd' ? 'even' : 'odd');
    $html .= '<tr class="'.$currentState.'">';
    $html .= '<td><a href="page.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">'. $row['Short Name of Fund'] .'</a></td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['I/C'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Fund Manager Company'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Class'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Special Class'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['TTR year-to-date %'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Total Expenses %'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Fund Size'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
echo $html;
```

**EDIT**: Updated code so it works.

Comment: This is what i got from this  syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I corrected the syntax using / instead of \.  The error is Warning: Division by zero in

Comment: It works with this correction   echo "<tr class=".$currentState.">";

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Was in a bit of a rush. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use CSS 3, try the [nth child](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/zebra-striping-tables-with-css3/) trick in your css:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) 
{
  background-color: #aaeeaa;
}
```

However, if you want to go ahead with odd / even classes, then you'll need a counter during your while loop and then alternate the odd / even classes when `count % 2 = 0`

Comment: I wish.  But I have to support older IE.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to use php in a logic way:D The trick is to make a dynamic class for your table rows. So basicaly you'll have 2 classes one for odd and one for eaven. I'll give you an example below (dont mind mind my project):

```
                            $counter="";
                      while ($upit_row = mysql_fetch_array($upit_run)){
                            $korisnik_id = $upit_row['korisnik_id'];
                $tip_id = $upit_row['tip_id'];
                                $tip = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT naziv FROM  tip_korisnika WHERE tip_id = '$tip_id'"));
                            $kor_ime = $upit_row['korisnicko_ime'];
                            $ime = $upit_row['ime'];
                            $prezime = $upit_row['prezime'];
                            $email = $upit_row['email'];
                            $counter++;
                            $class="";
                        if ($counter%2){
                           $class="even";
                      } else{
                           $class="odd";
                      }
```

CSS looks like this:

```
tr.odd{
    background-color:white;     
}
tr.even{
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
}
```

The counter will count every row that php generates which creates a number which u you dived by 2 and get odd and even numbers. After that you use the if statment to define your class:D
After that just insert the class variable in to the  like this:

```
echo "<tr class='$class'>";
```

or like this:

```
<tr class="<?php echo $class ?>">
```

PS. sorry for my english:/ Hope it helped.