# PHP MySQLi While Loop, Add <div> Tag Every 2nd Row

Tags: php

How do I in a MySQLi result set, using while() to display the results, insert a tag for every 2nd row so that the data shows up as this:

```
something
<div>something2</div>
something3
<div>something4</div>
something5
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zebra Stripe PHP MYSQL Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410534/zebra-stripe-php-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom counter:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($i == 0) {
        echo "something";
        $i=1;
    } else {
        echo "<div>something new</div>";
        $i=0;
    }
}
```

May well be a better way of doing it, but this gets the job done :)